# Show images from subfolders in tkinter

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a card game on tkinter, and I want to save the files in a sub-subfolder, this looks like this:

```
/
|-card_game.py
|-mypackages
     |-anyrandomstuff
          |-foo.py
     |-spam.py
     |-cards
          |-heart7.gif
          |-heart8.gif
          |-heart9.gif  #and so on all 32 cards of a standart card game
```

I know how to display images in tkinter, but only if they are on exactly the same level as `card_game.py`. As I don't want such a mess in my folders, I started to make researches on google and Stackoverflow. I didn't get any results, so I tried some different things like this:

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file='mypackages/cards/heart8.gif')#Here I tried: '.','\\','/', no results
photo_label = Label(image=photo)
photo_label.grid()
photo_label.image = photo

main.mainloop()
```

Here is the Error message, I get the sence quite well, but I don't know how to solve the problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "root\mypackages\cards\heart7.py", line 5, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file='mypackages/cards/heart7.gif')
  File "Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3393, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3349, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "mypackages/cards/heart8.gif": no such file or directory
```

What is the corrct way to "tell" python you want the Image in a subfolder?

Comment: Is `.../cards/heart7.py` your main executable, the file you run?

Comment: you can use an absolute path if you know it but the traceback states you are trying to initialize the card from a `.../cards/heart7.py` file, in which case it is in the same folder and you would do `file="heart8.gif"`

Comment: You forgot a slash, should be file='/mypackages/cards/heart8.gif' but can depend on your OS and assumes there are no directories above "mypackages", although here it says that you should also include "root"   File "root\mypackages\cards\heart7.py", line 5, in <module>

Comment: @Curly Joe: I tried it out and it gave me the same error as before

Comment: Then it is not the complete path.  You have to use the complete path. See what  os.getcwd() prints  https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os-file-dir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out what to do in this case:

You have to give the path like this:

```
./mypackages/cards/heart7.gif
```

This mounts the cwd as "." and lets me acces all files in the subfolders(actually, there was just a point missing!!!)

Comment: This is it!! just a pint (facepalm)